# Why is my circularly double linked list not referencing correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm at a loss, I've created a circularly double linked list with four directional pointers per node, but I'm getting unexpected values when I attempt to initialize the left and right pointers by traveling down the columns, and finding the rows with the corresponding rowID in the columns to the left and right of the current. Instead of initializing every node in every column, it initializes the pointers for the first node in every column, repeatedly.

My code with the DLL class, initialization with values, and attempting to print create left and right links between rows:

```
    class Node {
      constructor(data) {
        // *** Regular node
        // The data object containing the rowID, header, value, and any other key information for regular nodes;
        // for header nodes it contains the columnID.
        this.data = data;
        // The l and r links, connecting each of the headers together in the top row, as well as connecting each node in the matrix together,
        // all l and r link usages should be circular / doubly linked. 
        this.left = data.left ? data.left : null;
        this.right = data.right ? data.right : null;
        // The u and d links, all headers and nodes together, all usages should be circular / doubly linked.
        this.up = data.up ? data.up : null;
        this.down = data.down ? data.down : null;
        // The key to represent which column a row node belongs to.
        this.header = data.header ? data.header : null;
        // The ID to represent which row a node falls under, allowing exact precision by using both header and rowID to isolate a node.
        this.rowID = data.rowID ? data.rowID : null;
        // The key to represent which region a node falls under, so that that new values can be checked for validiity against the already existing values in the region.
        this.regionID = data.regionID ? data.regionID : null;
        // The value holding the number of blank representing character
        this.value = data.value ? data.value : null;
        // Whether or not the space is originally a blank, ergo mutable
        this.mutable = data.mutable ? data.mutable : null;
        // *** Header node specific
        // ID to define the node as the top of a column, and specifically which it is.
        this.columnID = data.columnID ? data.columnID : null;
        // A count of all nodes under the column, for general checking.
        this.nodeCount = data.nodeCount ? data.nodeCount : null;
      }
    }

    class DoublyLinkedList {
      constructor(data) {
        this._head = new Node(data);
        this._tail = this._head;
      }

      appendRow(columnID, data) {
        let currentColumn = this._head;
        let currentRow = currentColumn.down;
        while (currentColumn) {
          if (currentColumn.columnID == columnID) {
            while (currentRow != currentColumn) {
              if (currentRow == null || currentRow.down == currentColumn) {
                let newRow = new Node(data);
                newRow.down = currentColumn;
                newRow.up = currentColumn.up ? currentColumn.up : currentColumn;
                currentColumn.up = newRow;
                if (newRow.up.columnID != null) {
                  currentColumn.down = newRow;
                }
                currentColumn.nodeCount += 1;
                return newRow;
              }
              currentRow = currentRow.down;
            }
          }
          currentColumn = currentColumn.right;
        }
      }

      printList() {
        let rows = {
          A: '',
          B: '',
          C: '',
          D: '',
          E: '',
          F: '',
          G: '',
          H: '',
          I: ''
        };
        this.forEachColumn(column => {
          this.forEachRow(column, row => {
            rows[row.rowID] += row.data.value;
          });
        });
        return console.log(rows);
      }

      // Insert column header node at the end of the list
      appendColumn(data) {
        let newTail = new Node(data);

        newTail.left = this._tail;
        newTail.left.right = newTail;
        this._tail = newTail;
        this._head.left = this._tail;
        this._tail.right = this._head;
        this._head.nodeCount += 1;
        return this;
      }

      forEachColumn(callback) {
        let current = this._head.right;
        while (current && current != this._head) {
          callback(current);
          current = current.right;
        }
      }

      forEachRow(headerNode, callback) {
        let current = headerNode.down
        while (current && current != headerNode) {
          callback(current);
          current = current.down;
        }
      }
    }

const puzzleString = '..839.7.575.....964..1.......16.29846.9.312.7..754.....62..5.78.8...3.2...492...1';

function solve(puzzleString) {
    /* 
      Setting up the doubly circular linked list, using columns derived from the puzzleString...
      ...to populate each column / row with the correct initial values, and linking them all together.
    */
    // Array to hold the row letters
    const rowLetters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
    // Object to hold the column strings
    let columns = {
      1: '',
      2: '',
      3: '',
      4: '',
      5: '',
      6: '',
      7: '',
      8: '',
      9: '',
    };
    // Populating the columns object with the current values of each column
    let columnKeys = Object.keys(columns);
    columnKeys.forEach((key, outerIndex) => {
      let currentColumn = '';
      for (let innerIndex in columnKeys) {
        currentColumn = currentColumn.concat(
          puzzleString[innerIndex * 9 + outerIndex]
        );
      }
      columns[outerIndex + 1] = currentColumn;
    });
    // Set up the doubly circular linked list
    const SudokuMatrix = new DoublyLinkedList('head');
    // Add column headers to the DLL with unique IDs
    for (let columnCount = 0; columnCount < 9; columnCount++) {
      SudokuMatrix.appendColumn({ columnID: columnCount + 1 });
      // Add every row that belongs under each column, using the columns object to set values
      for (let rowCount = 0; rowCount < 9; rowCount++) {
        SudokuMatrix.appendRow(columnKeys[columnCount], {
          rowID: rowLetters[rowCount],
          value: columns[columnCount + 1][rowCount],
          header: columnKeys[columnCount],
          mutable: columns[columnCount + 1][rowCount] == '.' ? true : false,
        });
      }
    }
    // Connect all rows under the columns to each other, creating a circularly double linked list for each lettered row
    // For each column...
    SudokuMatrix.forEachColumn((column) => {
      let columnLeft =
        column.left.data == 'head' ? column.left.left : column.left;
      let columnRight =
        column.right.data == 'head' ? column.right.right : column.right;
      console.log('New column.');
      // Iterate over each row...
      SudokuMatrix.forEachRow(column, (row) => {
        let currentRowLeft = columnLeft.down;
        let currentRowRight = columnRight.down;
        while (row.left == null && currentRowLeft != columnLeft) {
          if (currentRowLeft.rowID == row.rowID) {
            row.left = currentRowLeft;
            console.log(row.left.data, 'left');
          } else {
            currentRowLeft = currentRowLeft.down;
          }
        }
        while (row.right == null && currentRowRight != columnRight) {
          if (currentRowRight.rowID == row.rowID) {
            row.right = currentRowRight;
            console.log(row.right.data, 'right');
          } else {
            currentRowRight = currentRowRight.down;
          }
        }
      });
    });
    SudokuMatrix.printList();
  }
```

Giving me the output:

[image: only the first row of every column]

This should be displaying values for every row, from every column, for a total of 81 entries, instead, only the first row from each column is being processed.

If I log the rowID of the row to the left, current, and the right, I get this:

[image: strange, possibly overlapping characters]

Which I'm not even sure how to begin debugging.
Any help is greatly appreciated, I feel very much out of my depth trying to diagnose the issue.

EDIT:
Manually appending three columns to the header node...

```
let testList = new DoublyLinkedList('head');
    testList.appendColumn({ columnID: 1 });
    testList.appendColumn({ columnID: 2 });
    testList.appendColumn({ columnID: 3 });
    console.log(testList);
```

...results in the expected output, of

```
DoublyLinkedList {
  _head: <ref *1> Node {
    data: 'head',
    left: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: [Node],
      right: [Circular *1],
      up: null,
      down: null,
      header: null,
      rowID: null,
      regionID: null,
      value: null,
      mutable: null,
      columnID: 3,
      nodeCount: null
    },
    right: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: [Circular *1],
      right: [Node],
      up: null,
      down: null,
      header: null,
      rowID: null,
      regionID: null,
      value: null,
      mutable: null,
      columnID: 1,
      nodeCount: null
    },
    up: null,
    down: null,
    header: null,
    rowID: null,
    regionID: null,
    value: null,
    mutable: null,
    columnID: null,
    nodeCount: 3
  },
  _tail: <ref *2> Node {
    data: { columnID: 3 },
    left: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: [Node],
      right: [Circular *2],
      up: null,
      down: null,
      header: null,
      rowID: null,
      regionID: null,
      value: null,
      mutable: null,
      columnID: 2,
      nodeCount: null
    },
    right: <ref *1> Node {
      data: 'head',
      left: [Circular *2],
      right: [Node],
      up: null,
      down: null,
      header: null,
      rowID: null,
      regionID: null,
      value: null,
      mutable: null,
      columnID: null,
      nodeCount: 3
    },
    up: null,
    down: null,
    header: null,
    rowID: null,
    regionID: null,
    value: null,
    mutable: null,
    columnID: 3,
    nodeCount: null
  }
}
```

The list is currently head <-> 1 <-> 2 <-> 3 (tail) <-> head, as it should be.

appending three rows to each of the columns...

```
let currentCol = testList.getHead().right;
    while (currentCol && currentCol != testList.getHead()) {
      let rowIDLetter;
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        switch (i) {
          case 0 : rowIDLetter = 'A';
          case 1 : rowIDLetter = 'B';
          case 2 : rowIDLetter = 'C';
        }
        testList.appendRow(i + 1, { header: i + 1, value: '1', rowID: rowIDLetter });
      }
      currentCol = currentCol.right;
    }
    console.log(testList.getHead().right);
```

...yields this output,

```
<ref *2> Node {
  data: { columnID: 1 },
  left: <ref *1> Node {
    data: 'head',
    left: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: [Node],
      right: [Circular *1],
      up: [Node],
      down: [Node],
      header: null,
      rowID: null,
      regionID: null,
      value: null,
      mutable: null,
      columnID: 3,
      nodeCount: 3
    },
    right: [Circular *2],
    up: null,
    down: null,
    header: null,
    rowID: null,
    regionID: null,
    value: null,
    mutable: null,
    columnID: null,
    nodeCount: 3
  },
  right: <ref *3> Node {
    data: { columnID: 2 },
    left: [Circular *2],
    right: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: [Circular *3],
      right: [Node],
      up: [Node],
      down: [Node],
      header: null,
      rowID: null,
      regionID: null,
      value: null,
      mutable: null,
      columnID: 3,
      nodeCount: 3
    },
    up: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: null,
      right: null,
      up: [Node],
      down: [Circular *3],
      header: 2,
      rowID: 'C',
      regionID: null,
      value: '1',
      mutable: null,
      columnID: null,
      nodeCount: null
    },
    down: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: null,
      right: null,
      up: [Circular *3],
      down: [Circular *3],
      header: 2,
      rowID: 'C',
      regionID: null,
      value: '1',
      mutable: null,
      columnID: null,
      nodeCount: null
    },
    header: null,
    rowID: null,
    regionID: null,
    value: null,
    mutable: null,
    columnID: 2,
    nodeCount: 3
  },
  up: Node {
    data: { header: 1, value: '1', rowID: 'C' },
    left: null,
    right: null,
    up: Node {
      data: [Object],
      left: null,
      right: null,
      up: [Node],
      down: [Circular *2],
      header: 1,
      rowID: 'C',
      regionID: null,
      value: '1',
      mutable: null,
      columnID: null,
      nodeCount: null
    },
    down: [Circular *2],
    header: 1,
    rowID: 'C',
    regionID: null,
    value: '1',
    mutable: null,
    columnID: null,
    nodeCount: null
  },
  down: Node {
    data: { header: 1, value: '1', rowID: 'C' },
    left: null,
    right: null,
    up: [Circular *2],
    down: [Circular *2],
    header: 1,
    rowID: 'C',
    regionID: null,
    value: '1',
    mutable: null,
    columnID: null,
    nodeCount: null
  },
  header: null,
  rowID: null,
  regionID: null,
  value: null,
  mutable: null,
  columnID: 1,
  nodeCount: 3
}
```

While the up link is correctly the last row in the column, the down link is incorrect, *also* linking to the third row, instead of the first row after the column header.

Comment: What is `puzzleString`?

Comment: When you create a new doubly linked list, you need to set `left` and `right` of the node to point to the initial node.

Comment: @Barmar It's an 81 character input string representing a Sudoku grid, I'm attempting to write an implementation of Donald Knuth's DLX in JS

Comment: I don't really care what it represents. It's just not in the code you posted, so trying to run it gets an error.

Comment: @Barmar My bad, for this testing it's simply '..839.7.575.....964..1.......16.29846.9.312.7..754.....62..5.78.8...3.2...492...1'

Comment: It would be nice if you edited the code snippet so it runs. Or simplify the test case -- we don't need the whole application, just enough to show how the DLL is supposed to be used and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I thought too much of the program might complicate readability. I've added all of the requirements, class methods and variables required.

Comment: We don't need the Sudoku solver. Just code that creates linked lists and shows the problem.

Comment: @Barmar All of the code that is instantiating the linked list and giving it values is under the SudokuSolver class.

Comment: We want a [mre] -- just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without lots of extraneous code unrelated to it. So just provide a simple script that creates a linked list and adds to it, without anything related to sudoku.

Comment: @Barmar How's that?

Comment: Just write some hard-coded `list.addRow()` and `list.addColumn()` calls and say what the expected result should be, then show what result you're actually getting.

Comment: @Barmar I added columns and rows manually, and updated the post with the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read all the code, but the most obvious problem is that you're not making the list circular when you create the first node.

```
  constructor(data) {
    this._head = new Node(data);
    this._tail = this._head;
    this._head.left = this._head.right = this._head;
  }
```

Comment: Ah, I'll try that out next

Comment: Changing this code has removed the overlapping / strange looking text, although I'm not sure why.